# Ошибка в работе с памятью поля

Tags: c++

Не могу никак исправить ошибку, связанною с работой с памятью. Проблема постоянно возникает в строке при проведении субституции, хотя быть ее не должно, ведь она объявлена с таким же размером памяти, как и mat в createArrow(). Доступа нет даже к первому элементу. В чем моя главная ошибка? Если поставить фиксированный объем памяти и передавать через Temp[Size][Size], то оно будет верно работать.

```
temp[i][j++] = matrix[row][col];
```

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class determinant
{
public:
    vector<int> vect;
    int size;
    determinant(int value, vector<int> vectr) {
        this->vect = vectr;
        this->size = value;
    }

    int** createarrow() {
        int** mat = 0;
        mat = new int* [size];
        
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            mat[i] = new int[size];

            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                mat[i][j] = vect[counter];
                counter++;
                cout << counter << endl;
                cout << mat[i][j] << endl;
            }
        }
        return mat;
        
    }


    void subMatrix(int** matrix, int ** temp, int p, int q, int n) {
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
                if (row != p && col != q) {
                    temp[i][j++] = matrix[row][col];
                    if (j == n - 1) {
                        j = 0;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int determinantOfMatrix(int** matrix, int n) {
        int determinant = 0;
        if (n == 1) {
            return matrix[0][0];
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            return (matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]);
        }
        int** temp = new int*[size];
        int sign = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            subMatrix(matrix, temp, 0, i, n);
            determinant += sign * matrix[0][i] * determinantOfMatrix(temp, n - 1);
            sign = -sign;
        }
        return determinant;
    }


};
```

```
int main() {
    vector<int> A = { 3,4,6,7,8,9,10,4,5 };

    determinant det(3, A);
    
    cout << "Determinant: " << det.determinantOfMatrix(det.createarrow(), 3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (j == n - 1)` -> `if (j == n)` в `subMatrix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вы в методе `determinantOfMatrix` выделили память `int** temp = new int*[size];`, а второе измерение не выделили. Вот оно и падает

Вам что-то типа такого надо видимо

```
int** temp = new int*[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    temp[i] = new int[size];
```

Потом не забудьте память почистить. А лучше возьмите вектор и пусть RAII делает грязную работу за вас

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, совсем выпало из головы. Сначала думал Вы скинули ошибочный вариант, потом сам его исправил, и получилось верно, а пересмотрев уже понял)